# Question about how to deal with a map of std::ostream objects into a class?

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, memory-management, c++17

I am dealing with the following class attribute:

```
std::map <std::ostream*, std::string> colors;
```

I was wondering if there is a way to replace the pointer to `ostream` with a better data-structure? I read [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp_questions/comments/eogoka/smart_pointer_behaviour_with_io_stream_objects/) that using a smart-pointer in this case is not a good idea and may be useless.

The `map` would be used only to store information and to access it to do simple stuff, without modifying the `ostream` objects, but simply comparing, replacing or adding them to the `map` itself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are these `ostream` pointers coming from?

Comment: *How should I correctly free the memory* -- Usage of pointers does not necessarily mean there is any usage of dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: @NathanOliver what do you mean? They are used like in the previous example

Comment: what previous example? Why do you use pointers to `ostream` as keys in a map?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you are right, I am not using the new operator, therefore I think I'll not have the problem of memory management. I am editing the question.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Because I want a map in which I can access a specific ostream object in order to do some operations

Comment: roughly speaking the question reads like "I have X, how can I replace X?", but it is unclear what you need X for or why you have it in the first place

Comment: some context is missing

Comment: @GianlucaBianco If these pointer are coming from objects that will outlive the map then using a raw pointer is fine.  It's only if you need the map to participate in the ownership of the lifetime of the `ostream` objects that you will need something like a `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @GianlucaBianco -- I see no issue if you are using the addresses of `ostream` objects you are maintaining.  Example: `yourmap.insert({&streamObject1,"object1"});yourmap.insert({&streamObject2,"object2"});`, etc.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I simply was wondering if there is a way to replace the pointer, speaking about a "general" case

Comment: there is nothing wrong with raw pointers as long as you do not use them to manage lifetime of dynamically allocated objects. From the (original) quesiton it seems like you arent doing that, but have some confusion about it. Do not use raw pointers to `new` or `delete` the objects and make sure the pointers are only used as long as the objects are alive, then you are fine and I see no reason to replace them with something else

Comment: @GianlucaBianco -- Yes, as #NathanOliver pointed out, if the map is only used as a "storage device", where the only thing it is going to be involved in is a place to map your stream objects to a string, then there is no issue.  If the map is going to be used in a more complex fashion, where it will participate in the creation, maintenance, etc. of those stream pointers, then that would require some more context on what role the map plays in all of this.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number that was exactly the answer I was searching for. Thank you very much.

Comment: @GianlucaBianco It would be good if you would rephrase the question for more clarity. I was lucky to have guessed what you are afraid of, but from the question its not really clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raw pointers should not be used to manage lifetime of dynamically allocated objects. As you mention nothing that goes against that, I assume the `std::ostream`s are stored elsewhere while your pointers are just pointers: They point somewhere. They do not participate in ownership, and they do not need to. In particular that means you are sure that the pointers are not used after the objects lifetime ended.

If all that applies then there is no need for smart pointers, because smart pointers are pointers that manage lifetime of objects. Raw pointers are pointers that do not participate in lifetime management. Before there were smart pointers there were owning raw pointers and non-owning raw pointers, and everything was much more messy. Nowadays, raw owning pointers can and should be avoided completely, and raw pointers and smart pointers aren't really alternatives to be considered for the same use cases.

> I was wondering if there is a way to replace the pointer to ostream with a better data-structure?

This of course depends on what you want to use the map for. Considering ownership and managment of lifetime a raw pointer is just the right choice to signal that the pointer does not participate in ownership and there is no apparent need to replace them with something else.